# pip freeze > requirements.pip loses some info on github installed packages

Tags: python, pip

I installed one of the fork I made using

`-e git://github.com/pcompassion/django.js.git@bd0f7b56d8ab2ae77795797fd10812d0b76883dc#egg=django.js-fork`

then I create a requirements.pip using `pip freeze > requirements.pip`

it shows

`django.js==0.8.2.dev0`

and it is not usable to use this in production.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug of pip

`https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/3258`

it's now fixed

I wonder why people downvoted the question...